# Subtract hours in Google Spread Sheet and convert to integer number

Tags: google-sheets

I have Entry and Exit time, and trying to get the value of 7.5 in the Total Real Hours.

I do not want to do normal time subtraction and get 07:30 but 7.5

```
Entry   Exit    Total Real Hours

08:30   16:00   7.5
```

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications [user 829174](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/151602/user829174). Please share with us what you searched/researched about this. For further details see [ask].

Answer (score 3):

The result is shown as duration in hours, but underneath it's a number representing fraction of a day. All you need to do is multiply it by 24.

So your formula should not be simply `=B2-A2`, but rather `=(B2-A2)*24`. And don't forget to format the result field as a number.

Comment: Simple and clean, nothing to break.